# Adding properties to an object using function and bracket notation

Tags: javascript, object

I have an assignment on a basic javascript class that I'm taking and I can't seem to get this to work. I have this unit test that was given to me:

```
describe('AddSixthProperty', function() {
      it('should add a food property with the value of bbq using bracket notation', function() {
        expect(objects.addSixthProperty()['food']).to.equal('BBQ');
      });
    });
```

I was given an empty function:

```
// don't touch this line
var mysticalAnimal = objects.mysticalAnimal();
function addSixthElement(){

return
}
```

So I tried this:

```
var mysticalAnimal = objects.mysticalAnimal();
objects.addSixthProperty = function(){
  mysticalAnimal['food'] = "bbq";
  return mysticalAnimal["food"];
};
```

It doesn't work. Our test page doesn't pass that. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What testing framework is it? Could it have anything to do with name differences in the test vs function name (`AddSixthProperty` vs `addSixthElement`)?

Comment: And with BBQ having different case?

Comment: No sorry that was my mistake should have copied it outright. I will edit the post. I'm not even sure what the testing framework is. Sorry, sounds like I should know but this is a prep project for a prep class to get in to a javascript bootcamp. In other words, I'm still new to this :)

Comment: I've now fixed it. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: I also added the correct case for BBQ and that didn't help. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `mysticalAnimal['food']`, and then the test tries to access `['food']` again, so it ends up accessing `'bbq'['food']`, which is `undefined`. You need to just `return mysticalAnimal`, as well as get all your letter cases right. Here's a little proof of concept:

```js
var objects = (function() {
  var animal = { mystical: true };
  
  return {
    mysticalAnimal: function() { return animal; }
  };
})();

var mysticalAnimal = objects.mysticalAnimal();

objects.addSixthProperty = function(){
  mysticalAnimal['food'] = "bbq";
  return mysticalAnimal;
};

var capturedAnimal = objects.addSixthProperty();

document.getElementById('result').innerText = capturedAnimal['food'];
```

```html
<p id="result" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function:

```js
var mysticalAnimal = objects.mysticalAnimal();
objects.addSixthProperty = function(){
  mysticalAnimal['food'] = "BBQ";
  return mysticalAnimal;
};

// Test the function
console.log(objects.addSixthProperty()['food'])
```